# How to close read and do an oral presentation on it in 12 minutes orl less?

Tags: style

so i am going to recieve a random passage from the book "1984" and will be given 12 minutes to read it, write all over it, and then do a 4+ minute oral presentation on it.

My teacher also says to focus on how the style affecs the meaning of the passage and to keep connecting everything with a general thesis......

**Any suggestions or guides?
Thanks!**

Comment: Vote to close as off-topic. I don't see how this relates to writing.

Answer (score 3):

I'd make sure you're very familiar with the book as a whole before you're given your twelve minutes.  If you already know what you think about the book, you can essentially use the excerpt your given as a source of evidence for ideas you already have.

It's been a while since I read 1984, but I don't remember any big style shifts.  So if you've already thought about the style and how it affects meaning in general, you've essentially already got your thesis.  Then it's just time to mine the passage for evidence, and go!

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I find that mindmaps are terrific for that. As you read the passage, sketch a mindmap of your thoughts and observations about style, meaning, the general thesis, noting any connections you notice among these.

Then for your presentation, work your way around the mindmap, diving as deeply into each branch as you think you have time for.